# How can I display a tux character in a shell script?

Tags: shell, unicode, special-characters

I realize this is very much of a long shot, but...

In shell scripts on Macs I can display an Apple character.  Is there any way to display a Tux character (or anything else associated with Linux) on Linux systems?

The simplest solution would be if there's something in the Unicode set that symbolizes Linux, whether a Tux or something else.  I haven't been able to find such a character through Googling, but maybe someone knows of one.

Another solution would be if there's some way (that I'm completely unaware of) to define characters on Linux, and display them in a terminal.  (Seems impossible, but who knows?  We used to do this on Commodore systems all the time!)

(I'm skipping the full backstory as to why this is useful, but the short version is that I'm looking for a way of displaying in as little space as possible in my `PROMPT` what kind of system I'm using, since I log into perhaps almost a hundred different servers, on different operating systems, and there are times a visual reminder would be very useful.)

If there does turn out to be a Unicode solution, I'll ask separate questions for Solaris and Windows.  But this is a long shot, so no point in asking those right now.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Apple character, , isn't actually an apple in Unicode; it's just U+F8FF, the last codepoint in the private-use range.  Other fonts do other things; for instance, in Code2000, it's apparently "KLINGON MUMMIFICATION GLYPH".

Comment: Indeed. The ‘Apple character’ has almost zero chance of being displayed as an Apple on any non-Apple computer.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but since I'm almost always logging in from a Mac, it wouldn't normally be a problem for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [penguin character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f427/index.htm) in [UNICODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). No font on my machine seems to be able to render it, but I'm using Linux, not MacOS, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: who the hell proposed that symbol? Nice find, btw

Comment: @Lie, that symbol is part of the [Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/miscellaneous_symbols_and_pictographs/images.htm) block, which was probably proposed by someone who thought Wingdings wasn't going far enough.

Comment: U+1F427 Penguin is one of the majority of symbols in this block that stem from the [emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), frivolous cutesy nonsense used by Japanese cellphones. The horror.

Comment: @bobince, [いやな感じ](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/denman/e/49a5df4dea615708e0919eeb6a3fa021).

Comment: Curious! The SE widget in the corner showed what must have been the original version of your comment, making the 感じ/漢字 pun more obvious. :-) Either way those 絵文字 certainly are いやな code points. I'm all for having Unicode standardise communications, but at the same time I kind of wish they'd have fallen in a pit full of fire instead.

Comment: The emoji character names in Unicode 6.0 are a problem: they've collided with a name from Unicode 1.0, which were not normative but which in fact were used.  The problem is the "BELL", which the C0 control codes used for code point 7, whose official name is now "<control>" along with many others. They should have named theemoji characters with a clarifying prefix the way they do for everything else. I don't know what we're going to do about this; it's something of a problem.

Comment: Are you guys referring to this  

Answer (score 5):

The character that displays an Apple logo on Apple computers,  ‹›,  is code point 0xF0 in MacRoman. Despite appearances, MacRoman is not an Italian hamburger but rather an 8-bit legacy character set carried forward from Apple's pre-Unix days. The mapping tables for MacRoman to Unicode place MacRoman 0xF0 at Unicode U+F8FF, which is in the  Private Use area. It has the Unicode regex properties `\p{Co}` (aka `\p{Other}`) and `\p{InPrivateUse}` (aka `\p{Private_Use}`).  Its script type is unknown, corresponding to the Unicode property `\p{Script=Unknown}`, also known as `\p{Unknown}`, `\p{Script=Zzzz}` or `\p{Zzzz}`. Its only other general categories are `\p{Graph}` and `\p{Print}`.

Besides its own logo at the very end of the private use area, Apple has [other private use characters](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/private_use_area.html#lucida): ‹› at U+F804 for an "eject" glyph,  ‹› at U+F802 for a "pencil" glyph, and ‹› at U+F803 for a glyph of a pointer into a sunburst.  These have no mapping into MacRoman.

There is nothing stopping a Linux system from grabbing some code point from the Private Use Area (which lies in plane 0 from U+E000 – U+F8FF), or from either of Supplementary Private Use Area A (plane 15: U+F0000 – U+FFFFD, or B (plane 16: U+100000 – U+10FFFD), and doing with it whatever it pleased.

These wouldn't be meaningful for interchange, but they *could* do it. It might even be fun to watch all the miscoded Java programs break on characters from up in the [astral planes](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2003/04/26/UTF) that are too big to fit into Java's (oxy)moronic `char` data type. ☺

In the very recently release Unicode 6.0, the [controversial Emoji](http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2009/11/whats-new-in-unicode-60.html) block does include code point U+1F427, PENGUIN.   Scant few fonts yet support Unicode 6.0, but you can see what it looks like here on [page 1256](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-6.0/U60-1F300.pdf) of Unicode 6.0.

Being an astral character, it would also cause conniptions in all those programming languages and environments whose broken character abstractions misrepresent characters as 16-bit entities instead of abstract characters.

(Hm, do we have a definitive list of those, those that expose the user to physical encodings instead of presenting abstract characters?  What else besides Java?)

So it's probably not a good idea except as an *agent provocateur*. Plus it doesn't really look all that much like Tux, anyway.

Personally, I really don't see the need to encode corporate logos as single code points. That's why we have GIFs and the like.

Comment: Plus, what would you use for BSD? U+1F47F IMP?

Answer (score 3):

While Googling I came across the following symbol, by accident. It's Tux and it seems to be pure text (unicode?). I'm not sure if it is something Linux or Ubuntu specific.
This is the symbol

```

```

According to Vim the character is:
<> 57344, Hex e000, Octal 160000

Comment: I just opened this post on Windows and the symbol displays as a typical 'unknown character' symbol in both Firefox and IE, so I guess it is something Linux or Ubuntu specific

Comment: `U+E000` is a private use character. It shows up as some Chinese character for me (on Linux, ironically).

Answer (score 3):

U+E000, the first character of the Private Use Area, is a Tux symbol in the Linux Libertine and Linux Biolinum fonts. These fonts are included in the fonts-linuxlibertine package in Debian and Ubuntu.

This won't help the OP's use case as these are not monospace fonts, but I'm posting this in case someone else needs this character.

Answer (score 1):

LUWM - Linux, Unix, Windows, Macs

no need to invent funny symbols